# How to inspect large and complex TypeScript types that don't fit in the popup?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a type that shortens to the following when I hover over a variable. Is there a native VSCode way or an inspection tool/extension that will allow me to step into the type and possibly into each nested branch, to see what it consists of?

```
type SupportedNetworkKeyz = {
    ethereum: string;
    avalanche: string;
    polygon: string;
    optimism: string;
    bsc: string;
    arbitrumOne: string;
    mantle: string;
    zora: string;
    base: string;
    goerli?: undefined;
    mumbai?: undefined;
    fuji?: undefined;
    ... 6 more ...;
    ethereumSepolia?: undefined;
} | {
    ...;
}
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I know there is no such feature.  But you can enable [`--noErrorTruncation`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#Output_Formatting_6256) to increase the display length up to some larger limit.

Comment: I typically just `declare const foo: SupportedNetworkKeyz; foo.` and then see what autocompletion gives me. Which does seem innefficient.

Comment: The relevant feature request is [ms/TS#28508](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28508); right now the language service doesn't provide this. Shall I write this up as an answer or am I missing something about the question?

Comment: @jcalz So, since "language service doesn't provide this", does it mean it is not even possible nowadays to write a userland extension to show the full types other than what is displayed in the popup? Like - showing the "... 6 more ..." or `| { ... }`. Yes, I guess you can write this as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: an extension to what, vscode?  Or TS?  I assume you can use the ts compiler api to implement whatever you want but maybe that's not "userland"?

Comment: @AlexWayne Haha yeah, I've been using that for years, also with some helper types like `Normalize<MyType>` or the likes, that resolve every type aliases, but it's not enough.

Comment: @jcalz I am not exactly sure where tsc ends and vscode begins, but in the end, when hovering over variables, I want to be able to display the full type without `...`. Not necessarily resolve type aliases into its underlying types, but allowing that would be a nice bonus.

Comment: @jcalz Using `--noErrorTruncation` as you suggested, did solve my problem in this particular case.